# slf4j + logback jboss wildfly doesn't work when I use ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender

Tags: jboss, wildfly, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to configure SLF4J and logback for my Spring Boot application deployed on Jboss Wildfly 12.0.0.Final. I have looked around and I have found solutions 
 that work only if I set the appender to a file but doesn't work when the appender is set as STDOUT.

It works fine if I run the application as Spring Boot but it doesn't when I deploy the war in Jboss.

This is my configuration:
logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <property name="DEV_HOME" value="${user.home}/logs" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/cyberfinancial.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M\(%line\) - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/cyberfinancial.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="cyberfinancial.v9" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>


</configuration>
```

This is the jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="logging"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Why if I choose the appender STDOUT I can't see the log anywhere?

Comment: Where is the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` located in your WAR?

Comment: Is under WEB-INF

Comment: What do you get if you execute `/deployment=*:read-children-names(child-type=subsystem)` in CLI? Also where is your logback.xml file located?